# Cannot convert type 'NinjectValidationFactory' to target type 'FluentValidation.IValidatorFactory

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ninject, fluentvalidation

I have been trying to resolve the "The type 'FluentValidation.ValidatorFactoryBase' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced" error I get when I do a simple NuGet install of FluentValidation, FluentValidation.MVC5 and Ninject.Web.Mvc.FluentValidation. The solutions suggested in several StackOverflow threads that worked when they were written seem to no longer provide a solution.

To understand the problem we can start at the top, using the NuGet UI to select * but not install * Ninject.Web.Mvc.FluentValidation. According to the dependency list it requires a version of FluentValidation-Signed ≥ 3.4.0.0 and < 4.0.

So, OK, we install an acceptable versions: FluentValidation-Signed -Version 3.4.6

Next, we need a version of FluentValidation.MVC. Of course we prefer 5, but if we examine its dependencies on the project website we see it requires ≥ 5.0 && ≥ 5.1. To get a version that will work we need to go back to FluentValidation.MVC4-Signed -Version 3.4.6

No we can install Ninject.Web.Mvc.FluentValidation -IgnoreDependencies (-IgnoreDependencies was added because it was described as required in the accepted answers in several of the StackOverflow threads)

Now I add this to my NinjectWebCommon class in App_Start:

```
        var ninjectValidatorFactory = new NinjectValidatorFactory(kernel);

        FluentValidationModelValidatorProvider
          .Configure(x => x.ValidatorFactory = ninjectValidatorFactory);
```

The solution builds successfully but .Configure(x => x.ValidatorFactory = ninjectValidatorFactory) has the red squigly line under it with the mouseover message: "Cannot convert type 'Ninject.Web.Mvc.FluentValidation.NinjectValidationFactory' to target type 'FluentValidation.IValidatorFactory'

Virtually all the posts I read on this topic are a couple years old. I'm stuck.

Comment: you should move your "UPDATE" section to an answer and accept - so that others who are searching for the same issue can see that it was solved.

Comment: Thanks. That is my intention. I'm testing now and as soon as i confirm that my solution works I'll move the update to the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following a suggestion from one of the threads I dispensed with adding the Ninject FluentValidation altogether. To clean up I first removed the two FluentValidation packages and the Ninject FluentValidation package and installed the most recent versions of the FluentValidation packages. Then i:

1. Grabbed the code for the NinjectValidatorFactory from GitHub [here][1] and added that class to my solution.
2. Wired up the Ninject factory again in my Ninject configuration like so:

   ```
   var ninjectValidatorFactory = new NinjectValidatorFactory(kernel);
   FluentValidationModelValidatorProvider
     .Configure(x => x.ValidatorFactory = ninjectValidatorFactory);

   // Bind all Fluent validators to their implementation.
   AssemblyScanner.FindValidatorsInAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly())
       .ForEach(match => kernel.Bind(match.InterfaceType).To(match.ValidatorType));
   ```

Now the red squigly lines are gone, the solutions builds, and everything works as intended.